# Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) pdo exception

Tags: php, laravel-5

I got many solution for this problem but none are working.

This is my controller

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Doctor;

 class DoctorController extends Controller
 {
   public function index(){
     $doctors = Doctor::all();
     return $doctors;
     return "this is a doctorController";
   }

  }
```

and This is my model

```
    <?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Doctor extends Model
 {
 //
}
```

and this is my Route.php

```
 Route::resource("doctor","DoctorController");
```

This is my .env file

```
  APP_ENV=local
  APP_DEBUG=true
  APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
  APP_URL=http://localhost

 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=medical
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=

 CACHE_DRIVER=file
 SESSION_DRIVER=file
 QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

 REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
 REDIS_PASSWORD=null
 REDIS_PORT=6379

 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
 MAIL_PORT=2525
 MAIL_USERNAME=null
 MAIL_PASSWORD=null
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I followed the solution of this 
     http://tutsnare.com/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-laravel-5/
and
   [Laravel 5.2: PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043302/laravel-5-2-pdoexception-in-connector-php-line-55-sqlstatehy000-1045-acces)

but none of them working .what should i do?

Comment: It might help others: I'd to clear the cache and restart the server after updating the details in the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

Its database connection error which says its password protected.
you can't leave it blank then (DB_PASSWORD=?) try using 'root' as password if you never assigned anthing different before.

Comment: well then i guess some password is set  ! you might want to reset it. try this :- https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

Comment: it's not password issue.I checked my config.inc.php file .passwird field are blank.  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

If possible provide your config/database.php file.
or go to config/database.php file and make changes as :

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'YOUR_DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'YOUR_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'YOUR_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

Comment: It's default configuration.you dont fave to set it.You have to change .env file .But anyway i followed ur suggestion .Still not working.

Comment: try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1,

Comment: Also check if you r mysql server is running :  mysqladmin -u homestead -p status Enter password: secret,

Comment: Try using DB_PASSWORD=secret in .env file

Answer (score 0):

If there is no password for the database, remove `DB_PASSWORD=` from the `.env` file. See if that solves your issue.